# pause python script to save output

Tags: python, save, pause

I am running a code in python to calculate some metric on adjacency matrices, where I loop through all adjacency matrices, iteratively writing to a numpy array, and then save the output of the array at the end of the loop.
As I can visualize the progress of the calculation, I see that the metric calculation on one of the matrices is taking way too long (e.g., instead of the usual 5 seconds, it's been hours). Here is my script:

```
longmat = scipy.io.loadmat('longmat.mat')
longmat = longmat['longmat']
matlength = longmat.shape
densval = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
betti = 0
output_long = np.zeros((264, 168, 12), dtype=float, order='F')

for z in range(matlength[2]): 
    for s in range(matlength[1]):
        temp = longmat[:, s, z] #vector of values
        tempr = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(temp,checks=True)

        for dens in range(len(densval)):
            G_tda = gd.graph_density(densval[dens], tempr)
            B = bet.Betti_k(G_tda, betti, verbose=False)
            output_long[dens, s, z] = B
            if B < 2:
                break

scipy.io.savemat('longout.mat', {'output_long': output_long})
```

I'd like to pause the script and save the array output up until this point and was wondering if this is possible. Thank you very much for your help!

Georgette

Comment: Please share the code so that one can guide :)

Comment: I added my code though I'm not sure if it will be helpful.

Comment: For your code part, what Nima suggested, something like that should be done. However, now if the code is already running its not possible to interrupt (since the code has nothing for it) and log. You would need to stop the script, re-run with more logging. Make sure to use `a` append flag if saving progress to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `if` statement.

```py
while true: # or a for loop
    #do the calculations here
    if condition: # condition is the metric before the one that takes too long to calculate
        open("test.txt", "a").write(output) # save the output to the file
```

This is only possible if you know which metric takes a long time to calculate.

UPDATE:
Now that you have shared your code, I can see a better option. You need to put the `scipy.io.savemat()` in the most inner loop. As below:

```py
longmat = scipy.io.loadmat('longmat.mat')
longmat = longmat['longmat']
matlength = longmat.shape
densval = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
betti = 0
output_long = np.zeros((264, 168, 12), dtype=float, order='F')

for z in range(matlength[2]): 
    for s in range(matlength[1]):
        temp = longmat[:, s, z] #vector of values
        tempr = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(temp,checks=True)

        for dens in range(len(densval)):
            G_tda = gd.graph_density(densval[dens], tempr)
            B = bet.Betti_k(G_tda, betti, verbose=False)
            if B < 2:
                break
            output_long[dens, s, z] = B
            scipy.io.savemat('longout.mat', {'output_long': output_long}, appendmat=True)
```

This way at the end of each loop `B` is appended to the output file. Note that `appendmat=True` ensures no overwrite will happen. You can see its documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html#scipy.io.savemat). I didn't use `else`, but you can use it for beauty. It's not necessary anyway.

Comment: Hello Nima, thank you for responding to my question. However, if I already started running the script without having inserted this if statement, is it still possible to pause the script now and save the output?

Comment: Usually no if its trapped in an endless loop you will need to stop the script or else it will just enlessly run

Comment: I don't think it's an endless loop, just computationally heavy because there was an adjacency matrix in there with a strange non gaussian distribution of values.

Comment: I updated the answer. Maybe it's what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you so much Nima for your help! I have not integrated that into my script.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pause a script and save the until-that-point array output without having added, before running the script, a line of code inside my loop to iteratively save the output to the array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).